# Como pegar valores em função de um outro valor?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice

Estou querendo somar o valor (e mostrar em uma célula qualquer) da célula Cx quando Dx for igual a 1 e somar os valores de Cy quando Dy for 2.

Por exemplo: Na foto, quando o valor da célula Dx for 1, quero que o valor de Cx (da mesma linha) vá para L3 e assim L3 ter a soma de todos os valores da coluna C que tiver 1 na coluna D.

[image: foto]

Comment: O fechamendo desta pergunta está sendo [debatida no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6907/28595)

Answer (score 3):

A fórmula para `L3`:

```
=SUMIF(D5:D9;"=1";C5:C9)
```

Traduzido `SOMASE` como @Isac disse, se não estiver usando nomes de funções em inglês.
*Ferramentas -> Opções -> LibreOffice Calc -> Fórmula -> Use nomes de funções em inglês.*

Documentação: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SUMIF_function